# Understand the map function in Python - Index reassignment

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to understand how the *map* function works in Python with this usage :
I have

```
def permutate(table, block):
"""Permutate this block with the specified table"""
    return(map(lambda x: block[x], table))

ls_bits =    [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
IP =         [2,3,1,4,7,0]

ls_bits= permutate (IP, ls_bits)
print (list(ls_bits))


>>> 
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

It does exactly what I want: it takes the value of `i` index in `ls_bits` (`ls_bits[i]`), and reassigns this value to the index of value `IP[i]` in `ls_bits`. For exemple, `ls_bits[1] = 1`, `IP[1] = 3`, so after the map function, `ls_bits[3] = 1`.

But I don't understand why (I found this method on the web) since I am not using any function in the "map method"

Thanks in advance for your help, I hope I was clear enough for you to understand my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *lambda expression* is passed as a function to `map`. It is defined as a nested function to be able to reference the other function argument `block`. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the lambda keyword. This function returns the sum of its two arguments: `lambda a, b: a+b`. Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required. They are syntactically restricted to a single expression. Semantically, they are just syntactic sugar for a normal function definition. Like nested function definitions, lambda functions can reference variables from the containing scope [...]

The function `map()` is used to apply the callable (first argument) sequentially to the iterable (second argument). It builds a list of the callable's return values for each element contained in the iterable in return.

Altogether, it's a shorthand for

```
def permutate(table, block):
    """Permutate this block with the specified table"""
    def index(x):
        return block[x]
    ret = []
    for x in table:
        ret.append(index(x))
    return ret
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 0):

`map` applies the function `lambda x: block[x]` to each of the elements of the iterable `table` and returns an array of the results

Answer (score 0):

```
def permutate(IP, bits):
    return(map(lambda x: bits[x], IP))
    # To apply lambda function on IP list
    # x is any elem of IP list
    # return the index of elems in the IP list

    # bits[2] ---> 0. becuase index of 2 in the IP list is zero.
    # bits[3] ---> 0. becuase index of 3 in the IP list is zero.
    # bits[1] ---> 1. becuase index of 1 in the IP list is one.
    # bits[4] ---> 1. becuase index of 4 in the IP list is one.
    # bits[7] ---> 0. becuase index of 7 in the IP list is zero.
    # bits[0] ---> 0. becuase index of 0 in the IP list is zero.

    ### Visualization ###
    # elems of bits          --> 0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
    # index of elems of btis --> 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

bits = [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
IP   = [2,3,1,4,7,0]

print ('indexes of IP list :', list(permutate(IP, bits)))
```

Comment: You just look at the above program.